# Git-flow fails with "fatal: no tag message? / Tagging failed. Please run finish again to retry"

Tags: git, git-flow

I am using [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to manage a project.  I am getting the following message when issuing `git flow release 
finish foo`:

```
fatal: no tag message? 
Tagging failed. Please run finish again to retry.
```

Here is the sequence of steps to reproduce, with a brand new git 
repository and a single file:

```
touch test.txt 
git init 
git add . 
git commit -m "Initial commit" 
git flow init 
[defaults accepted] 
git flow release start 1.0 
echo "Line 1" >> test.txt 
git add . 
git commit -am "Line added" 
git flow release finish '1.0'
```

At this point, error message above pops up, and Vim is called up to 
add a tag.  When I add the tag and save, I end up on the master 
branch, with the release/1.0 branch still existing.  Any ideas what is 
going wrong?  Git flow version is 0.4.1.

Thank you.

Comment: Could not reproduce, using git flow version 0.4.2-pre on Ubuntu Natty.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  I'm encountering this issue on Windows 7 using MSYSGIT.

Answer (score 13):

Before finishing your release/hotfix branch, add the tag manually:

```bash
git tag -a v0.1.2 -m "release_added"
```

Please don't include spaces in the message, then finish the release/hotfix, and then you will be given a window to add a message.

If you add the tag and you have issues with the message, change the message using:

```bash
git tag <tag name> <tag name> -f -m "<new message>"
```

Please don't add spaces in the message.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, it was a core.editor setting that was giving me problems. It turned out I had set up Gedit (no idea how). Try something like `git config --global core.editor "vim"` or edit the editor line in your .gitconfig.

Comment: FYI, if you want gedit to work as the core editor, it has to be started with `-s` and `-w` arguments.

Comment: I set it to 'nano' and now is good. It was 'vi' I think.

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this by adding -n at the end of the command like below.

```
git flow hotfix finish 'hotfix name' -n
```

-n means no tag.

Comment: The `-n` needs to go before the hotfix name, not after. https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#hotfix